# Obtain the previous fragment before the last in Android Navigator

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am searching for the fragment previous to the last (n-2). I have the following to iterate over the fragments. However, I am getting just the last fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();

if(fragments != null){
  for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
    List<Fragment> childrenFragments = fragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
    if (childrenFragments != null){
      for(Fragment childFragment : childrenFragments ){
        String fragmentName= childFragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(fragmentName); // Just printing the last fragment
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried with the following:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack();
    Fragment fragment= fm.getFragments().get(0);
    String fragmentName = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

In both ways I am getting NavHostFragment as result.

Is there a way to access the stack in the Navigator component and get the name for the n-2 Fragment?

Thanks a lot